# Stored Procedure /string split function not working properly in subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, asp-classic

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 that utilizes a user defined "split string" function to handle multiple checkbox entries coming from a classic ASP page.

When I select 0 boxes it works fine. When I select 1 box, it works fine. When I select more than 1 box, it only includes the first string value and not the other values from the other checkboxes selected.

This is a follow up question on another post [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57226252/passing-and-using-variables-through-asp-sql-storedproc), but no need to look there, if I can get this part working I am good!

Here is the user-defined function I am reusing:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitString]
    (@Input NVARCHAR(MAX), 
     @Character CHAR(1))
RETURNS @Output TABLE (Item NVARCHAR(1000))
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @StartIndex INT, @EndIndex INT

    SET @StartIndex = 1

    IF SUBSTRING(@Input, LEN(@Input) - 1, LEN(@Input)) <> @Character
    BEGIN
        SET @Input = @Input + @Character
    END

    WHILE CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input) > 0
    BEGIN
        SET @EndIndex = CHARINDEX(@Character, @Input)

        INSERT INTO @Output(Item)
            SELECT SUBSTRING(@Input, @StartIndex, @EndIndex - 1)

        SET @Input = SUBSTRING(@Input, @EndIndex + 1, LEN(@Input))
    END

    RETURN
END
```

Here is where I get the parameters from the ASP page. `artStatus` is the checkbox values.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_invsearch]
    @inv_number VARCHAR(14) = NULL,
    @number     VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @sales_id   VARCHAR(8) = NULL,
    @bill_name  VARCHAR(100) = NULL,
    @inv_status VARCHAR(10) = 'closed',
    @dateofsale VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @enddate    VARCHAR(10) = NULL,
    @artStatus  VARCHAR(20),
    @inv_date   VARCHAR(10) = NULL
```

Here is there query where I call the function:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ad_info
WHERE 
    (@number IS NULL OR RTRIM(number) LIKE @number) 
    AND (@sales_id IS NULL OR RTRIM(sales_id) LIKE @sales_id)
    AND (@bill_name IS NULL OR RTRIM(bill_name) LIKE @bill_name)
    AND (@inv_number IS NULL OR RTRIM(inv_number) LIKE @inv_number)
    AND (@dateofsale IS NULL OR DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, dateofsale), 0) BETWEEN @dateofsale AND @enddate )
    AND (@artStatus IS NULL OR RTRIM(track_id) IN (SELECT * FROM dbo.SplitString(@artStatus, ',')))
    AND (@inv_status IS NULL OR RTRIM(ISNULL(inv_status, '')) LIKE @inv_status)
    AND (@inv_date IS NULL OR DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, inv_date), 0) = @inv_date)
```

If I substitute hard coded values in place of the function call, it gets the correct data set, so it's somewhere in the function or me calling it that seems to be the problem.

In other words, this works as expected:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    ad_info
WHERE 
    (@number IS NULL OR RTRIM(number) LIKE @number) 
    AND (@sales_id IS NULL OR RTRIM(sales_id) LIKE @sales_id)
    AND (@bill_name IS NULL OR RTRIM(bill_name) LIKE @bill_name)
    AND (@inv_number IS NULL OR RTRIM(inv_number) LIKE @inv_number)
    AND (@dateofsale IS NULL OR DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, dateofsale), 0) BETWEEN @dateofsale AND @enddate)
    AND (@artStatus IS NULL OR RTRIM(track_id) IN ('AP', 'MC'))
    AND (@inv_status IS NULL OR RTRIM(ISNULL(inv_status, '')) LIKE @inv_status)
    AND (@inv_date IS NULL OR DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY, 0, inv_date), 0) = @inv_date)
```

What am I missing? Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks like that was the trick! Jon or whoever posted a minute ago asking about spaces being in the results. When I used the replace function in the SP, it seems to be working now!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was having spaces in the comma sep string.

So it was getting this: AP, MC, MP

instead of AP,MC,MP

So I used the replace function in the SP:

```
SET @artStatus = REPLACE(@artStatus, ' ', '')
```

seems to be working thanks again!